# Accessing Squid Proxy over internet

Tags: squid

I recently finished installing Squid on a VPS I have in the US and its working fine locally (I verified by setting http_proxy variable and using lynx).

I want to access this proxy over the internet (as an anonymizer) so that I can see how some ads show up for US traffic on my website. I have setup authentication so abuse is not a problem. However, I am not able to access the proxy over the internet. I have set the following rule in squid.conf

http_access allow all

Is this not possible to do what I want or I am missing something? The port 3128 is open in the firewall so that is not an issue. Squid is running on 0.0.0.0

Thanks
Prateek

Comment: Have you confirmed that port 3128 is not blocked by your ISP or by a local firewall?

Answer (score 2):

you have to check squid logs (usually at /var/log/squid/access.log
i am sure that access is denied form squid. You should enable that.

I recommend to tunnel squid via ssh to get secure access, for checking ads from US thats the best way to do it (forcing an squid)

Comment: Indeed - tunneling over SSH extremely sensible precaution. +1 :)